# Throws UaException for getting BuildInfo with Kepware UA server

Tags: milo

I use `ReadNodeExample` class to try to get node info of Kepware UA server. Everything is fine but the BuildInfo, and I get the following exception:

```
19:00:32.723 [main] ERROR ClientExampleRunner - Error running client example: UaException: status=Bad_NotFound, message=A requested item was not found or a search operation ended without success.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_NotFound, message=A requested item was not found or a search operation ended without success.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at ReadNodeExample.run(ReadNodeExample.java:52)
    at ClientExampleRunner.run(ClientExampleRunner.java:88)
    at ReadNodeExample.main(ReadNodeExample.java:22)
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: status=Bad_NotFound, description=A requested item was not found or a search operation ended without success.
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.FutureUtils.failedUaFuture(FutureUtils.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.FutureUtils.failedUaFuture(FutureUtils.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.nodes.UaVariableNode.lambda$getTypeDefinition$6(UaVariableNode.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient.lambda$receiveResponse$13(UaTcpStackClient.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.ExecutionQueue$PollAndExecute.run(ExecutionQueue.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And here's the result of full `serverStatus`:

```
19:00:31.549 [main] INFO  ReadNodeExample - ServerStatus=ServerStatusDataType{StartTime=DateTime{utcTime=131455372857187500, javaDate=Wed Jul 26 18:08:05 CST 2017}, CurrentTime=DateTime{utcTime=131455404299062500, javaDate=Wed Jul 26 19:00:29 CST 2017}, State=Running, BuildInfo=BuildInfo{ProductUri=urn:WIN-S8JCN9R7PFA:Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6:UA%20Server, ManufacturerName=Kepware, ProductName=KEPServerEX, SoftwareVersion=6.2, BuildNumber=460, BuildDate=DateTime{utcTime=131433109160000000, javaDate=Fri Jun 30 23:41:56 CST 2017}}, SecondsTillShutdown=0, ShutdownReason=LocalizedText{text=null, locale=null}}
```

I'm not very sure whether the problem is due to Kepware or milo client itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated, but the problem is that Kepware's `BuildInfo` node doesn't have its required `HasTypeDefinition` reference pointing to the `BuildInfoType` VariableType.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Please forgive me for lack of knowledge in the OPC UA specifications, but it seems that Kepware is certificated for OPC UA as client interface according to the OPC foundation's website [link](https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/kepserverex). Could you please tell me what is the correct format of `BuildInfo` node that milo should work properly?

Comment: @TonnyTc the BuildInfo node needs a HasTypeDefinition reference. All Variable and Object nodes need a HasTypeDefinition reference pointing to a VariableType or ObjectType. The Compliance Test Tool must not be validating the structure of the address space for servers under test right now.